# How to create a functions.php in child theme?

Tags: functions

I want to create a functions.php file in my child theme and put some code in it, but i can't do it because everytime i create a functions.php file and put a code in it an error occurs.

Does anybody know the way to do it?

```
<? php

add_action('iphorm_post_process_1', 'mytheme_create_wp_post', 10, 1);
function mytheme_create_wp_post($form)
{
$title = $form->getValue('iphorm_1_1');
$content = 'Content: ' . $form->getValueHtml('iphorm_1_30') . '<br />';
$content .= 'Link: ' . $form->getValueHtml('iphorm_1_11') . '<br />';
$content .= 'Creator: ' . $form->getValueHtml('iphorm_1_36') . '<br />';
$content .= 'Category: ' . $form->getValueHtml('iphorm_1_39') . '<br />';
$content .= 'Facebook: ' . $form->getValueHtml('iphorm_1_26') . '<br />';
$content .= 'Area: ' . $form->getValueHtml('iphorm_1_15') . '<br />';
$content .= 'Date: ' . $form->getValueHtml('iphorm_1_8') . '<br />';
$content .= 'Time: ' . $form->getValueHtml('iphorm_1_9') . '<br />';
$content .= 'Terms: ' . $form->getValueHtml('iphorm_1_32') . '<br />';
$content .= 'Info: ' . $form->getValueHtml('iphorm_1_35') . '<br />';

$post = array(
    'post_title' => $title,
    'post_content' => $content
    'post_status' => 'draft'
);

wp_insert_post($post);
}

?>
```

P.S. I use this code to automatically take the data from a submitted form (QuForm Plugin) and create a draft post. I already work it in the parent theme.

```
[Wed May 01 00:26:01 2013] [warn] [client 188.4.45.92] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING, expecting ')' in /var/www/vhosts/e-win.gr/httpdocs/wp-content/themes/e-win/functions.php on line 20, referer: http://www.e-win.gr/
[Wed May 01 00:26:06 2013] [warn] [client 216.52.242.14] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING, expecting ')' in /var/www/vhosts/e-win.gr/httpdocs/wp-content/themes/e-win/functions.php on line 20
[Wed May 01 00:26:06 2013] [warn] [client 188.4.45.92] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING, expecting ')' in /var/www/vhosts/e-win.gr/httpdocs/wp-content/themes/e-win/functions.php on line 20, referer: http://www.e-win.gr/
[Wed May 01 00:26:23 2013] [warn] [client 188.4.45.92] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING, expecting ')' in /var/www/vhosts/e-win.gr/httpdocs/wp-content/themes/e-win/functions.php on line 21, referer: http://www.e-win.gr/wp-admin/admin.php?page=options.php
[Wed May 01 00:29:12 2013] [warn] [client 188.4.45.92] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING, expecting ')' in /var/www/vhosts/e-win.gr/httpdocs/wp-content/themes/e-win/functions.php on line 21, referer: http://www.e-win.gr/wp-admin/admin.php?page=options.php
[Wed May 01 00:29:41 2013] [warn] [client 157.56.93.230] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING, expecting ')' in /var/www/vhosts/e-win.gr/httpdocs/wp-content/themes/e-win/functions.php on line 21
[Wed May 01 00:29:46 2013] [warn] [client 173.199.114.187] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING, expecting ')' in /var/www/vhosts/e-win.gr/httpdocs/wp-content/themes/e-win/functions.php on line 21
[Wed May 01 00:30:08 2013] [warn] [client 188.4.45.92] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING, expecting ')' in /var/www/vhosts/e-win.gr/httpdocs/wp-content/themes/e-win/functions.php on line 21, referer: http://www.e-win.gr/wp-admin/admin.php?page=options.php
[Wed May 01 00:37:57 2013] [warn] [client 188.4.45.92] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected $end in /var/www/vhosts/e-win.gr/httpdocs/wp-content/themes/e-win/functions.php on line 31, referer: http://www.e-win.gr/wp-admin/admin.php?page=options.php
[Wed May 01 00:42:05 2013] [warn] [client 188.4.45.92] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected $end in /var/www/vhosts/e-win.gr/httpdocs/wp-content/themes/e-win/functions.php on line 31, referer: http://www.e-win.gr/wp-admin/options-general.php?page=wp-viewer-log
```

Comment: Add the code of your `functions.php` to your question please.

Comment: You are doing it the right way. The error is being caused by the code inside your functions.php. If you show it here we may be able to tell you why.

Comment: The file _must_ start with `<?php` – no white space inside.

Comment: @vancoder you mean the parent theme's functions.php or the child's?

Comment: If this is a direct duplication of code in the parent theme's functions.php, you don't need it at all, as the parent will do the work.

Comment: No, now i only have the code in the child's theme!

Comment: "*...but i can't do it because everytime i create a functions.php file and put a code in it an error occurs*" - **please add the exact error message** to your question.

Comment: @ChipBennett i put it!

Comment: Remove _all_ code from your functions.php. Do you still get the error?

Comment: @vancoder If i have only the php start and end tag the blog works good! If i add the code it gives me an error.

Comment: And this code is definitely _not_ in the parent theme's functions.php also?

Comment: @vancoder yes! You can check if you want in the main question, i added the error log!

Comment: You don't have 31 lines of code, so how are you getting an error on line 31? This is odd, as I wouldn't expect a 500 error from a broken functions.php.

Comment: @vancoder thanks a lot! I'd messed up everything! Can you help me with something else or i have to create a new thread?

Comment: New thread please.

Comment: no idea if this is still relevant: the posted code in this line `'post_content' => $content` is missing a comma.

Comment: No it is missing a comma because it is the last element...Although @vancoder helped me to solve it! Thank you too!

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the space between `<?` and `php` at the very start of your file.

Incorrect:

```
<? php

add_action('iphorm_post_process_1', 'mytheme_create_wp_post', 10, 1);
function mytheme_create_wp_post($form)
{
```

Correct:

```
<?php

add_action('iphorm_post_process_1', 'mytheme_create_wp_post', 10, 1);
function mytheme_create_wp_post($form)
{
```

This is causing a simple syntax error.

Comment: I did it but again it gives me an error: HTTP 500 (Internal Server Error)!

Comment: All you did was remove the space, and now you get the Internal Server Error, is that correct? Nothing else changed?

Comment: Yes! I editted as you told me above and it gives me the same error.

Comment: This was the error you had all along? Then, this is a different problem.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @vancoder's answer, you are also missing a comma in the `$post` array.

```
$post = array(
    'post_title' => $title,
    'post_content' => $content, // <-- that comma is missing in your code
    'post_status' => 'draft'
);
```

That causes the `T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING` error when the script hits the following line.

This problem is just bad PHP. You should develop with [debugging enabled](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress) and you would spot this yourself.

Comment: Ok you are right!